# PXSelector on Attribute list doesn't sort by sortorder

Tags: acumatica

I have a PXSelector attribute set on a field for a custom DAC / screen that uses the Acumatica Attributes (table CSAttributeDetail) for the lookup as follows:

```
         [PXSelector(typeof(Search<CSAttributeDetail.valueID, 
                            Where<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID, Equal<Constants.toDoType>>, 
                            OrderBy<Asc<CSAttributeDetail.sortOrder>>>),
                     typeof(CSAttributeDetail.valueID),
                     typeof(CSAttributeDetail.description))]
```

But - the Order by seems to make no difference.  Is there something I need to add to make sure it orders by the SortOrder?

Here's a screenshot of the attribute list:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, the PXSelectorAttribute can only sort by foreign key or substitute key, if any defined. Sorting by any other field will make no effect.

Comment: So the only way to sort this is to put numbers in front of the values, such as 00Value1, 01Value2, 02Value2, etc.  Correct?

Comment: One more thing - how does the combo box that results from an attribute list order them by sortOrder?  Somehow it does it.  Is there any way to do that in our grid?

Comment: Can you please update your initial question with a screenshot of the attribute list ordered by sortOrder? I'm not sure where to find it.

Comment: Done.  It's a custom attribute list.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! It's a combo box input, not a selector. My answer was specific to PXSelector inputs, not PXDropDowns.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Since the use of that attribute dropdown is able to be filtered by the sort order, why can't the PXSelector?  Is there a way to use the dropdown instead of the PXSelector in a custom grid?

Comment: @pmfith, the combobox items configured inside an attribute are assigned to a combo box at runtime via FieldSelecting handler - this is how they get sorted. Yes, you can create a dropdown instead of the PXSelector in a custom grid - there is an example for that in the T200 class documentation. I's also worth checking how the PXStringListAttribute.SetList method is used in source code to utilize it in a RowSelected handler to sort combo box items at the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort in some special way, you can consider creation of custom selector, and then in method GetRecords() add sorting criteria.

Consider following code sample:

```
public class SelectorCustomerContractAttribute : PXCustomSelectorAttribute
{
    private Type selectorField;
    private Type contractFld;

    public SelectorCustomerContractAttribute(Type selectorField, Type contractField)
        : base(typeof(DRDocumentRecord.refNbr))
    {
        if (selectorField == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("selectorField");

        if (contractField == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("contractField");


        if (BqlCommand.GetItemType(selectorField).Name != BqlCommand.GetItemType(selectorField).Name)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("moduleField and docTypeField must be of the same declaring type. {0} vs {1}",
                BqlCommand.GetItemType(selectorField).Name, BqlCommand.GetItemType(selectorField).Name));
        }

        this.selectorField = selectorField;
        contractFld = contractField;
    }

    public override void FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)
    {           
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable GetRecords()
    {
        var cache = this._Graph.Caches[BqlCommand.GetItemType(selectorField)];
        var cbs = (ContractBillingSchedule) cache.Current;
        cache = this._Graph.Caches[BqlCommand.GetItemType(contractFld)];
        var contract = (Contract) cache.Current;
        var result = new List<int>();

        if (cbs.BillTo == "M")
        {
            result.Add(1);
        }

        if (cbs.BillTo == "P")
        {
            result.Add(2);
        }
        if (cbs.BillTo == "S")
        {
            result.Add(3);
        }
        result.Add(4);
        return result.OrderBy(a => a.someCriteria);
    }
}
```

Usage of the selector can be like this:

```
public class ContractBillingScheduleExt : PXCacheExtension<ContractBillingSchedule>
{
    #region UsrCustomerContact
    public abstract class usrCustomerContact : IBqlField, IBqlOperand
    {
    }
    [PXDBInt]
    [SelectorCustomerContract(typeof(ContractBillingSchedule.billTo), typeof(Contract.contractID))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer Contact", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    public virtual int? UsrCustomerContact { get; set; }
    #endregion

}
```