# Sorting data in PXSelector

Tags: acumatica

I'm using this selector and i want to sort (Asc) by LineNbr

```
PXSelector(typeof(Search<Choixfournisseur.inventoryCD, Where<Choixfournisseur.reqNbr, Equal<Current<Choixfournisseur.reqNbr>>>,**OrderBy<Asc<Choixfournisseur.lineNbr>>**>), new Type[] { typeof(Choixfournisseur.lineNbr), typeof(Choixfournisseur.orderQty),typeof(Choixfournisseur.itemDesc),typeof(Choixfournisseur.curyEstUnitCost),typeof(Choixfournisseur.curyEstExtCost),typeof(Choixfournisseur.inventory) },ValidateValue = false, Filterable = true)]
```

But it doesnt work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm8ZQ.png)

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: As far as I know this is a limitation in Acumatica selector. It will sort by key fields first. In your case that would be 'Code Article' column I believe.

Comment: See this thread, Ruslan from Acumatica says this is by design. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591109/pxselector-on-attribute-list-doesnt-sort-by-sortorder

Answer (score 0):

A workaround you can do, is that you can create a projection which is ordered by the LineNbr field. In the selector you can reference the projection instead of the Main DAC. The selector should then reflect the results as you want them.